# Can't connect to JIRA Python through REST api https url

Tags: python, ssl, https, connection, jira

I try to connect to a jira dev sandbox through https but it comes up with an SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol error

This is the error log/stack trace. I try both ports 8080 and 443 but no joy.

```
>>> from jira.client import JIRA


>>> options = {'server':'localhost:8080'}

>>> auth = ('username', 'password')
>>> jira = JIRA(options, auth)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 88, in __init__
    self._create_http_basic_session(*basic_auth)
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1369, in _create_http_basic_session
    r = self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 284, in post
    return self.request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 241, in request
    r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 638, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

>>> options = {'server':'localhost:443'}

>>> auth = ('username', 'password')
>>> jira = JIRA(options, auth)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 88, in __init__
    self._create_http_basic_session(*basic_auth)
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1369, in _create_http_basic_session
    r = self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 284, in post
    return self.request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 241, in request
    r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 631, in send
    raise ConnectionError(sockerr)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it now. Port 8080 was set up and was not a defauld for http connection whether as for https I used validation manipulation basically setting validate = False in the jira-python method body

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from jira.client import JIRA
options = {'server':'localhost:8080'}
jira = JIRA(options)
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username', 'password'))
```

If it doesn't help, any chance the have [`OpenSSL` conflicts](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/990/)?

> When curl is linked against OpenSSL 0.9.8 and tries to access a server running OpenSSL 1.0.0, the SSL handshake fails with:
>   curl: (35) error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)